# Install gwt 2.1 over 2.4

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using gwt 2.4 over eclipse (OS ubuntu 11.10). I have to use the google maps library for gwt. I tried to use this library with gwt 2.4 but there is a few incompatibilities. After a quick research i concluded to install gwt 2.1. But when i tried to install it from the "install new software" of eclipse and give the link that i found [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7) is trying to reinstall the gwt v 2.4. Any ideas??
I just want the repository location of the gwt 2.1 for eclipse 3.7.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be the **gwt-maps-v3** library would it? If so, I compiled a version that is compatible with GWT 2.4. As it stands, the downloadable jar is only compatible with `<= 2.2`. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the GWT SDK (as a zip file), unpack it and then point Eclipse at it. Look at the Google preferences in Eclipse to "add a new SDK".

See also http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6204